# In Komodo Edit, is there a way to add an additional file type and have it use an existing vim syntax file?

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

I write in a custom scripting language a lot. I have a vim syntax file which is great for syntax highlighting when editing in vim.

I write in several languages throughout the day on an almost daily basis. I usually use Komodo Edit since it recognizes the file types of all my other languages. Unfortunately, for my custom scripting language, Komodo just sets it as file type "Text".

Is there a way I can tell Komodo that files with extension .xyz are of file type XYZ? If I have a xyz.vim file, is there an easy way to have Komodo use that for syntax highlighting or an easy way to import/convert to a Komodo format so I don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new language for Komodo using the wizard...

Project > New from template > Create Komodo Language

and just fill in the blanks (like a list of your language's keywords and file name extension).

The current code it generates to implement this is a little buggy, though it still works ok. If you are using Komodo 9 may see a pop-up log warning box. In 8, the warning still occurs though you need to pull up the error log yourself to see it (Help > Troubleshooting > View log file). A fix is promised in the 9.2 version.